# How to position an element on top of react native navigation bottom tabs

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native navigation bottom tabs, and I want to create a custom "bottom sheet" popup component, but I want that component to come over the bottom tabs. Does anybody know how to position elements on top of the bottom tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You have to use react-native-portalize. Just wrap the elements you want to be rendered  on top in a `<Portal></Portal>`. This will place it above a Bottom Tab navigator.

```
import { Portal } from 'react-native-portalize';

const FooterButton = () => {
return(
    <Portal>
      <View>
       <Text>I appear above the Tab Navigator!</Text>
      </View>
    </Portal>
);
export default FooterButton;
```

Don't forget to wrap the whole app in the the Host:

```
//In app.js
import { Host } from 'react-native-portalize';

const App = () => {
return (
    <Host>
       <NavigationContainer>
          <AppNavigator />
       </NavigationContainer>
    </Host>
)
}
export default App;
```

NOTE: The elements inside the Portal, do not clear when the navigator navigates to another screen. So to get around this, you have to only display the Portal, when the screen is active. Thankfully React Navigation 5+ provides a useIsFocused hook that accomplishes this perfectly.

```
import { Portal } from 'react-native-portalize';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

const FooterButton = () => {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  // Only display the button when screen is focused. Otherwise, it doesn't go away when you switch screens
  return isFocused ? (
    <Portal>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <View style={styles.footer}>{props.children}</View>
      </View>
    </Portal>
  ) : null;
};
export default FooterButton;
```

If you want a modal-style popup, you can wrap react-native-modalize and wrap it with react-native-modalize

[Thanks to livin52 on Reddit for the solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/kun6zq/comment/gitlbt7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: I eventually came to this solution but was too lazy to come back to share, thank you for taking the time to write this response, this is exactly correct!